# PHP - Triple Des 3DES CBC encrypt result not match

Tags: php, encryption, 3des

I am trying to implement a 3DES encryption/decryption with CBC mode in PHP.

```
<?php
$plaintext = hex2bin('781723860c06c2264608f919887022120b795240cb7049b01c19b33e32804f0b');
$algorithm = "DES-EDE3-CBC";
$key = hex2bin('AB94FDECF2674FDFB9B391F85D7F76F2');

$ivHex = "00000000";
// encryption
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $algorithm, $key,  OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $ivHex);
echo bin2hex($encrypted);

//RESULT : 685677557a4663584634656156584b38316a766c59754b316f7837742f703274724d69556c3966384f75673d
```

Echo :**685677557a4663584634656156584b38316a766c59754b316f7837742f703274724d69556c3966384f75673d**

But it try it on web. Expected response is : **72C29C2371CC9BDB65B779B8E8D37B29ECC154AA56A8799FAE2F498F76ED92F2**

[image]

fix my code Php to echo Expected response as website.

Comment: The website uses *2TDEA* because of the 16 bytes key, whereas in the PHP code `DES-EDE3-CBC` specifies *3TDEA*, s. [keying options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options). To be consistent with the website, *2TDEA* must be applied (with `DES-EDE-CBC`). Alternatively, you can stick with `DES-EDE3-CBC` and explicitly expand the key according to *K1|K2|K1*.

Comment: In addition, PHP/OpenSSL implicitly Base64 encodes, which the website does not do and which can be disabled with `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`.

Comment: it's work!!! Thanks u. 
------
$plaintext = hex2bin('781723860c06c2264608f919887022120b795240cb7049b01c19b33e32804f0b');
$algorithm = "DES-EDE-CBC";
$key = hex2bin('ab94fdecf2674fdfb9b391f85d7f76f2');


$ivHex = hex2bin("0000000000000000");

// encryption
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $algorithm, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA , $ivHex);
echo 'Encrypted: ' .bin2hex($encrypted);
echo'<br>';